# Rails Associations Through Multiple Levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, hierarchy

I am relatively new to Rails and am working on a project that involves multiple, "nested" levels of data. I am having issues making the proper associations so I can get all the child elements of a model 3 levels higher. Here is an example of the models:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I have implemented a relationship in the `Country` model, `has_many :cities, :through => :states` and have tried to call `Country.first.cities.all`, which works. However, I am having issues accessing all the people in a given country when I try `Country.first.cities.all.people.all` in the `People` controller.

What is the best way to deal with this sort of association situation? Should I add a foreign key to each of the children tables, such as `country_id`, so that I can get all the `People` in a `Country`? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You could go with named_scopes or scopes(in Rails 3.) There's a good railscast for it too!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that Country.first.cities.all is an array, and each of it's elements has the method people, instead of the entire collection of cities. You'll notice that this works:

```
Country.first.cities.first.people.all
```

Because the first city of the first country has the people method. To get a list of all people in a country, you could do the following in a single query:

```
People.joins(:city => {:state => :country})
  .where(:country => {:id => Country.first.id}).all
```

Comment: This answer may be old, but it helped me a lot to understand how work with (3 and 4) nested joins, I was trying to do it reversed and of course if didn't work. Now it's even even easy to understand! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's beacouse

```
Country.first.cities.all
```

is a collection of cities and it doesn't have people method.

You should go with

```
Country.first.cities.all.each do |city|
    city.people
end
```